# How to pass a function that's a property of another object into a function and call it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

If I have an object in Javascript and one of its properties is a function:

```
function cow() {

    this.timesMooed = 0;

    this.sayMoo = function () {
        this.timesMooed++;
        return "moo";
    };
}
```

Say I also have another function that takes some function as an argument, calls it and records the result:

```
var actionResults = [];
function doAction(action) {
    actionResults.push(action());
}
```

Now let's put this into practice and see what happens:

```
var jerry = new cow();
doAction(jerry.sayMoo);
console.log(actionResults);
// Outputs ["moo"] -this is correct
console.log(jerry.timesMooed);
// Outputs 0 -uh oh
```

How can I pass in the function so that it's `Jerry` that is running the function?

Comment: `doAction(jerry.sayMoo.bind(jerry));`

Comment: This question has been asked and answered dozens, if not hundreds, of times on SO. Search and research harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the reference to the function `doAction` and then call it with `action()`, the calling context changes and this is what determines the value of `this`. You need to use `bind` to keep the value of `this` locked to `jerry` :

```js
function cow() {
    this.timesMooed = 0;
    this.sayMoo = function () {
        this.timesMooed++;
        return "moo";
  }
}

var actionResults = [];
function doAction(action) {
    actionResults.push(action());
}

var jerry = new cow();
// use bind, which makes a function with `this` set properly
doAction(jerry.sayMoo.bind(jerry));

console.log(actionResults);
console.log(jerry.timesMooed);
```

Alternatively you can use arrow functions `=>` which bind `this` lexically:

```js
function cow() {
    this.timesMooed = 0;
    // use arrow function here instead
    this.sayMoo = () => {
        this.timesMooed++;
        return "moo";
  }
}

var actionResults = [];
function doAction(action) {
    actionResults.push(action());
}

var jerry = new cow();
// no need to bind() now
doAction(jerry.sayMoo);

console.log(actionResults);
console.log(jerry.timesMooed);
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: This is exactly the depth that I wanted; thankyou so much for a clear and thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `this` keyword is used in a method and we call that method from a receiver object and `this` is not bound to the object that we expect it to be bound to i.e. jerry in this case.

Note that `this` value in methods and functions must be set explicitly when we need a specific object bound to the function’s `this` value.

**Solution**

Solution is simple to use correct context

i.e. we want `this` to refer to jerry hence while invoking doAction method with sayMoo method of jerry object use bind function call and pass jerry as this argument

```
doAction(jerry.sayMoo.bind(jerry));
```

Answer (score 1):

try creating a constructor

```js
       class cow {   
            constructor(){
               this.timesMooed = '';
            }      
            sayMoo() {
               this.timesMooed+=1;
               return "moo";
            }
        }
            
            var actionResults = [];
            function doAction(action) {
            actionResults.push(action);
            }
            
            var jerry = new cow();
            doAction(jerry.sayMoo());
            console.log(actionResults);
            console.log(jerry.timesMooed);
```

Comment: This is good, except for the fact that (1) it's unnecessary and (2) it address the OP's issue--he want's to push the function call itself, to be executed later (with the right `this`), not the result of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark_M says the better way is to use arrow function but this feature force you to use ES6 instead of ES5 because [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) introduce in ES5.
Another way is to use benefits of variable scope like this:

```
        function cow() {
            this.timesMooed = 0;
            var that = this;
            this.sayMoo = function (){
                that.timesMooed++;
                return "moo";
            }
        }

        ...
```